# Load-balancing switch for netty application(or web application)

Tags: java, web-services, web-applications, netty, load-balancing

I want all incoming packets to pass through one switch, which dispatches them to one of many servers (or services); 
once a TCP connection is established, the load balancer will send all packets for that connection to the same server.

I also want to add a session management layer to it *(i.e the same session always goes to the same server)*.

So, I'm looking for a framework, technique or tools (extensions, anything basically) which provides me most of this functionality so I can keep that as my base layer and add other specific functionality over it.

Comment: What you describe in the first sentence is basic load-balancing.  In the second, you are looking for session affinity, which will require packet inspection, presumably to include SSL/TLS off-load -- the balancer would need to decrypt the traffic to view the session info (SESSIONID or etc).  A less sophisticated approach is IP+time-based affinity (as long as the same client connects withing the time window), it gets directed to the same server.  There are many hardware solutions, here is a review of some software: http://linuxpoison.blogspot.com/2008/09/opensource-load-balancing-software.html